# How can one scale a SharePoint Excel Web Services Web Part chart?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, charts, web-parts

I'm please with my the Excel chart being displayed as a web part in our SharePoint 2010 site... however, it's coming out too large, taking up most of the screen.

I had hoped I could change the width/height of the web part, but that just creates me scrollbars without scaling the chart.

This must be possible somehow, surely? Anyone know how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... you can :)

So, it doesn't seem to work when the chart is on a dedicated sheet (although this is often nicer inside Excel).

However, to scale the chart for the web part, it needs inserted into a standard sheet and then it can be resized.

Simples, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the height and width of chart web part otherwise you can follow scrolling like below.

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;padding:3px; border: solid 1px black;"></div>
```